# How to get Data from current fragment to other fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am using Fragment for my current application. Here I have one Fragment FA and I am navigating to the other Fragment FB and I have added FA to the backstack as I want to come to FA fragment on some event to be done in FB fragment. I have a done button in the fragment FB. On Click of that button I need to do two things in the fragment FB which are as follows :-

(a). I need to finish the current fragment FB.
(b). Secondly, I need to pass some data from FB to already existing Fragment FA as I have added it to backstack.

I have just started using Fragments and don't know much about them and I want to sort out this problem.Can anyone suggest something for this, any Help would be appreciable.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: here [Communicating Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from one fragment to another something like below.

```
  Fragment fragment;
    fragment = new SingleImage();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("img",actorsList.get(position).getImage());
    bundle.putString("desc",actorsList.get(position).getDesc());
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit();
```

means you can add arguments with fragment to pass to another.

and you can get that data in another fragment using below code

```
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

    if(bundle != null)
    {
        tvdesc.setText(bundle.getString("desc"));
        img_url= bundle.getString("img");
     }
```

Since you want only one back stack entry per Fragment, make the back state name the Fragment's class name (via getClass().getName()). Then when replacing a Fragment, use the popBackStackImmediate() method. If it returns true, it means there is an instance of the Fragment in the back stack. If not, actually execute the Fragment replacement logic.

```
 private void replaceFragment (Fragment fragment){
 String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();

 FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
 boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate (backStateName, 0);

 if (!fragmentPopped){ //fragment not in back stack, create it.
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
    ft.commit();
   }
  }
```

Comment: But my Fragment which is getting the data is already in backstack and I have to refresh the list when user press the Done button.

Comment: How can I refresh my list if the fragment containing list is already in the backstack?

Comment: i did not get what you want exactly but i have edited my answer see if it help you.

Comment: Can you go through my question once again, I didn't get you edited answer.

Comment: A) finish the current fragment FB you can use this link https://gist.github.com/jankovd/9303738  and             B)to pass some data from FB to already existing Fragment FA you can write  above code in to onclick of done button  i have given where you can pass and get data through bundle.